# How can I get the output of a sql script using Ruby Active Record?

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord, sqlplus, oracle-call-interface

Notes:  Using Ruby 2.4, oci8 / oracle enhanced adapter.

I was using sqlplus to execute some DDL / DML I have. Basically this:

```
system "echo / | sqlplus  #{db.username}/\"#{db.password}\"@#{db.host}:#{db.port}/#{db.sid} @\"#{file_to_execute}\" > #{@SQLOUT_LOG}"
```

I want to move away from using sqlplus and use active record instead.  So I got this working:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read("#{file_path}"))
```

And that does basically the same thing, except:  I cannot access the 'script output' that I got from SQLplus (or even SQLDeveloper).  This 'execute' function returns table rows, which I usually don't care about or need.

I just want a string of the output result of the script after I run it. Example:

> Procedure MYPROCEDURE compiled
>
> 3 rows inserted.

etc....

Answer (score 0):

```
puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read("#{file_path}"))
```

Comment: The result is 0, not a string of the output.

Comment: hitting `result.methods` will lead you on the path to the correct method you're looking for, if at all possible. Your question was relatively vague and without a verifiable working example it's very hard to help you get the output you're looking for.

Comment: I mean, I'm not sure how I can clear it up any more.  I literally just want the output of the statements I'm running.  The same output that I would normally get for running a script through SQLplus or SQL developer.


When I run `results.methods` i get results for integers.  I don't think I'm accessing the information I want correctly using this.

Comment: Try firing `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT); ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 0;` prior to running the query, and then fire the query. Does that return what you're looking for? If it does, you could capture the output of the log.

Comment: That just outputs the contents of the script in pink letters, but no actual results output.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've determined that there is no way to get the information I'm trying to get using ActiveRecord, and will try to look into other options or keep using sqlplus.